# Trigger is not working in SQL Server 2012 on runtime?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger

In SQL Server 2012,

1. I create two tables `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`
2. After that, I created a trigger for `TABLE1`
3. Trigger name: `PUSH_TABLE2`

   ```
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PUSH_TABLE2]
       ON [dbo].[TABLE1]
       AFTER INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @col1 VARCHAR(20), @col2 VARCHAR(20), @col3 VARCHAR(20)
       SELECT @col1=column1, @col2=column2, @col3=column3 FROM INSERTED

       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE2] VALUES (@col1, @col2, @col3);

   END
   ```
4. After creating the trigger `PUSH_TABLE2`, I test with below insert query manually on `TABLE1`, triggers works perfectly and its populate the data to both `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`.

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('session1', 'value1', 'type1');

   (1) rows affected.

   (1) rows affected.
   ```

The problem is if the data is populated through application, it will only populate the data to `TABLE1` only, seems trigger is not working. Is it because of my trigger script problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your trigger only handles single-row inserts. That was as true in SQL Server 2008 as it is in SQL Server 2012.

Given two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
    col1 varchar(20) NULL,
    col2 varchar(20) NULL,
    col3 varchar(20) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
(
    col1 varchar(20) NULL,
    col2 varchar(20) NULL,
    col3 varchar(20) NULL
);
```

A trigger that handles multi-row inserts is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.PushTable2
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT dbo.Table2
        (
            col1, 
            col2, 
            col3
        )
        SELECT 
            INS.col1,
            INS.col2,
            INS.col3
        FROM Inserted AS INS
    END;
END;
```

Test it with:

```
INSERT dbo.Table1
    (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
    ('session1', 'value1', 'type1');

INSERT dbo.Table1
    (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
    ('session2', 'value2', 'type2'),
    ('session3', 'value3', 'type3');

SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table2 AS T2;
```

Results:

[image: Results]